# How do I create indexes concurrently with flyway in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

Postgres allows the creation of indexes without locking the table using the CONCURRENTLY option. This options is not allowed in a transaction, so when it is added to a flyway migration script flyway fails:

ERROR: Caused by org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot run inside a transaction block

ActiveRecord supports the [disable_ddl_transaction!](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b337390889cb4a9f80ed08daf072a043f0e7ddf3) to address this scenario. Does flyway support some way to run such a script outside of a transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at this point. All migrations currently run within a transaction. Feel free to file an enhancement request in the issue tracker.

Comment: 2015 - it is still not possible to run create index concurrently with flyway ;-)

Comment: Correction: just an example seems to be missing, feature already implemented: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1072

Comment: Seems like someone built this feature for the Java API  Can this be done via command-line version of flyway?

Answer (score 13):

This was implemented in Flyway 4.1, see ticket [851](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/851) and [Non-Transactional PostgreSQL Support in Flyway](https://github.com/porchdotcom/blog/issues/9) (link broken).

This functionality works by detecting that a statement should be executed without a transaction. As far as I know, this is currently only supported for PostgreSQL.

> The first hurdle is detecting when a migration needs to be run outside
> of a transaction. Two paths forward are evident. The first path, [..],
> is to create a filename annotation. The second path is to add a
> statement parser to Flyway that detects non-transactional commands and
> runs them in the appropriate isolation level. Despite the extra work
> it would require on their part, the Boxfuse team was steadfast on
> following the second path. It provides the better user experience for
> Flyway users in the long term.

By default a migration that is executed this way, should only contain statements that need to be executed without a transaction. Mixing it with transactional statements is not allowed by default, and needs to be enabled with a property.

> Creating a condition that migrations must not mix transactional with
> non-transactional statements creates a restriction that may introduce
> an unseen problem for a user in the future. In case this unknown
> situation requiring DDL that normally would be run inside of a
> transaction needs to be handled, a property called
> *flyway.allowMixedMigrations* is added to the configuration. By default it is false. I strongly suggest to never turn it on.

The statements that are handled non-transactionally are determined by code in [`PostgreSQLParser`](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/postgresql/PostgreSQLParser.java):

```java
@Override
protected Boolean detectCanExecuteInTransaction(String simplifiedStatement, List<Token> keywords) {
    if (CREATE_DATABASE_TABLESPACE_SUBSCRIPTION_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()
            || ALTER_SYSTEM_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()
            || CREATE_INDEX_CONCURRENTLY_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()
            || REINDEX_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()
            || VACUUM_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()
            || DISCARD_ALL_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean isDBVerUnder12 = true;
    try {
        isDBVerUnder12 = !parsingContext.getDatabase().getVersion().isAtLeast("12");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("Unable to determine database version: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    if (isDBVerUnder12 && ALTER_TYPE_ADD_VALUE_REGEX.matcher(simplifiedStatement).matches()) {
        return false;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @ZhongxiaZhou I updated the link to the class in Flyway code (and the code), but the second link simply no longer exists and I could find no new location, nor is it in archive.org. I have left the link in place as I quote parts from it.

Answer (score 1):

For flyway >= 9.1.2, it tries to be compatible with pgbouncer by default, and creating concurrent index will hang the process.

To fix it we need to set `postgresqlTransactionalLock` -
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/postgresqlTransactionalLock

Example for gradle

```
flyway {
    pluginConfiguration = [
        postgresqlTransactionalLock: "false"
    ]
    //...
}
```

Example for custom runner

```java
FluentConfiguration flywayConfiguration = Flyway.configure()
        .baselineOnMigrate(true)
        .dataSource(url, username, password) // FROM CONFIG
        .outOfOrder(true)
        .table("flyway_schema_history");
flywayConfiguration.getPluginRegister()
        .getPlugin(PostgreSQLConfigurationExtension.class)
        .setTransactionalLock(false);
Flyway flyway = flywayConfiguration.load();
flyway.migrate();
```

Taken from github issue: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3508

Comment: Hi Pavel - adding the configuration to the Gradle build script isn't effective in my experience, although defining the configuration on the command line does work. I've tried Gradle 6.8.3 and 7.4. What version of Gradle are you using that this configuration works with?

Comment: gradle 7.4.2. What error did you get?

Comment: No error. Applying a migration with CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY just hangs. I'm testing with Flyway v9.4.0.

Comment: The problem script is labeled as `[non-transactional]` by Flyway. I do get the `cannot run inside a transaction block` error when trying a script containing `REINDEX TABLE CONCURRENTLY`.

Comment: I tried again, my migrations hangs too, running with env variable works `FLYWAY_POSTGRESQL_TRANSACTIONAL_LOCK=false` and if initializing flywayConfiguration in code works too. might be a bug in gradle plugin

Answer (score -2):

According to this post:

[Flyway migration hangs for postgres CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614429/flyway-migration-hangs-for-postgres-create-index-concurrently)

You can just add NT as a prefix to your migration so

V201609121806__create_index_for_table.sql

becomes

NTV201609121806__create_index_for_table.sql

Comment: This actually doesn't work.  Refer to Axel Fontaine's answer for this. The custom resolver PR never got merged and I'm not sure how to actually solve this.